# Linear transformation range question

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that If $V, W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over R and $T1 : V → W$ and $T2 : V → W$ then are linear $rank(T_1+T_2)\leq rank(T_1) + rank(T_2)$, but I cannot connect my steps to the statement

Here is my attempt:

suppose $y \in ran(T_1+T_2)$  then $y=(T_1+T_2)(x)$
By linearity, $y=T_1(x)+T_2(x) \in ran(T_1)+ran(T_2)$
and here is the part I stuck on. Is there a theorem that says that $ran(T_1+T_2) \subseteq ran(T_1)+ran(T_2)$ ? Searching for my linear transformation book and I didn't see any theorems that have this property. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you can't find that theorem, you just proved it!

Comment: @user847970 how does y in both $ran(T_1+T_2)$ and $ran(T_1)+ran(T_2)$ infer that one is a subset of another?

Comment: You assumed that $y$ was an arbitrary element of $\operatorname{ran}(T_1 + T_2)$, and logically concluded that $y \in \operatorname{ran}(T_1) + \operatorname{ran}(T_2)$. That is, every element of $\operatorname{ran}(T_1 + T_2)$ is an element of $\operatorname{ran}(T_1) + \operatorname{ran}(T_2)$. That is,$$\operatorname{ran}(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq \operatorname{ran}(T_1) + \operatorname{ran}(T_2).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y \in ran(T_1+T_2)$, then $y=(T_1+T_2)(x)$ for some $x \in V.$

Since $(T_1+T_2)(x)=T_1(x)+T_2(x)$ and $T_1(x) \in ran(T_1)$ and $T_2(x) \in ran(T_2)$ we get $y \in ran(T_1)+ran(T_2).$

This shows that $ran(T_1+T_2) \subseteq ran(T_1)+ran(T_2).$